# django rest swagger does not display properly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use django-rest-swagger to document my APIs, so I follow the [official doc](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) to setting in my django app. But it doesn't display properly like below:

[image: does-not-display-properly]

I was using Nginx+supervisor+gunicorn to serve my django app. Is it possible that they cause it?

The proper page should be like below:

[image: s]
<sub>(source: [django-rest-framework.org](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/img/django-rest-swagger.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your static files is not configured. You can see this in firebug or chrome dev tools.

1. Read the documentation how to deploy static files (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/)
2. Check that rest_swagger in your INSTALLED_APPS.
3. Check that STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT settings is setted properly.
4. Call collectstatic management command.
5. Check that nginx configured to serve static files in STATIC_ROOT folder.

Comment: yes, you are right. Finally, I found that there no static files for rest_swagger. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How does one do step 5, Check that nginox is configured to serve static files in STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: Something like this in nginx config
    `location /static/ {
            access_log off;
            alias   /path/to/your/static_root/;
            expires -1;
        }`